# How do I do this ternary operation in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
....
.....
if ($prod_price->RecordCount()>0) {
              $p_price = $prod_price->fields['options_values_price'];
          }
          else
          {
              $p_price = $orders_products_query->fields['products_price'];
          }
          $p_price = ($p_price>0)?$p_price:$orders_products_query->fields['final_price'];
......
..........
```

As you can guess from the above, I am running two different queries and checking 3 fields to determine the variable $p_price in PHP. I want to condense this in a single query, the conditions being:
If field1 is Null, use field2, if field2 is 0, use field 3.

The first part can be solved with IFNULL(field1,field2)....but what do I do about the second part? Should I use case? I need the most efficient solution in terms of execution speed, cause this is part of an extremely large query.

**EDIT:**

Since it seems the question isn't clear to some of you, take this as an alternative.

`IF(IFNULL(field1,field2)>0,IFNULL(field1,field2),field3)`
The above MySQL query condition works with the above mentioned logic, but as you can see, it evaluates field1 and field2 twice for NULL checking, which I don't believe is very efficient, so I am looking for a better query/condition to rewrite the same thing.

Comment: The best way to find out is by trying it on a large dataset and do some benchmarks.

Comment: where is the `mysql` part ??

Comment: The `mysql part` is basically me asking for the best way to rewrite this in a mysql query: `IF(IFNULL(field1,field2)>0,IFNULL(field1,field2),field3)`

Comment: Edit your question and insert the MySQL part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `IF(condition, val-if-true, val-if-false)` in MySQL.

You can also nest the `IF()` functions, something like this:

```
IF(field1 IS NOT NULL, field1, IF(field2 <> 0, field2, field3))
```

This corresponds to:

- If field1 is NOT NULL, use field1, otherwise...
- If field2 is non-zero, use field2, otherwise...
- Use field3

Comment: thanks, but field2 is not NULL, it is either 0 or some other number

Comment: @aoi I've updated my answer to check field2 for non-zero instead of not-null.

Answer (score 2):

The standard SQL COALESCE function looks like what you need:

COALESCE(a, b, c, d, "banana") means that the expression will take on the first non-null value it encounters, working from left to right.   It is quite efficient, taking only a few processor cycles.

It can take on as many parameters as you need, from two, to a gazillion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like below

```
lets Try this :

select if(Id is null, 0, id) as Id;
```

And also mysql providing very good [document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) to you conditional statement

Also if one more cases you can use like

```
SELECT USER_ID, (CASE USER_ID WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FIRST_USER FROM USER
```

let me know if i can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ISNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) or [IS NOT NULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null) in Mysql.